# AssImp won't load OBJ files

Tags: c++, glfw, assimp

I'm using AssImp to load a model created in Blender and exported into the .obj file format. And GLFW, GLEW and GLM to render the loaded model. My problem is that right now AssImp wont even load the model and I just get the error message `ERROR::ASSIMP::Unable to open file "MyFile.obj"`. 
This is the class I'm using to import the model and later draw it.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <SOIL2/SOIL2.h>
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
#include "MeinMesh.h"


using namespace std;

GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory);

class Model
{
public:
    //Konstruktor mit pfad zum Model aufrufen
    Model(const GLchar* path)
    {
        this->loadModel(path);
    }
    // Modell zeichnen
    void Draw(Shader shader)
    {
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->meshes.size(); i++) 
        {
            this->meshes[i].Draw(shader);
        }
    }

private:
    //Daten für das Modell
    vector<Mesh> meshes;
    string directory;
    vector<Texture> textures_loaded;

    void loadModel(string path)
    {
        //Datei mit Assimp auslesen
        Assimp::Importer importer;
        const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);

        if (!scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode)
        {
            cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP::" << importer.GetErrorString() << endl;
            return;
        }

        this->directory = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));

        this->processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);
    }

    void processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
    {
        for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
        {
            aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];

            this->meshes.push_back(this->processMesh(mesh, scene));
        }

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
        {
            this->processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
        }
    }

    Mesh processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
    {
        vector<Vertex> vertices;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        vector<Texture> textures;

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
        {
            Vertex vertex;
            glm::vec3 vector;

            vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
            vertex.Position = vector;

            vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.Normal = vector;

            if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0])
            {
                glm::vec2 vec;

                vec.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
                vec.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;

                vertex.TexCoords = vec;
            }
            else
            {
                vertex.TexCoords = glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
            }

            vertices.push_back( vertex );
        }

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
        {
            aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];

            for (GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            {
                indices.push_back( face.mIndices[j] );
            }
        }

        if (mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0)
        {
            aiMaterial *material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];

            vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse");
            textures.insert(textures.end(), diffuseMaps.begin(), diffuseMaps.end());

            vector<Texture> specularMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular");
            textures.insert(textures.end(), specularMaps.begin(), specularMaps.end());
        }

        return Mesh(vertices, indices, textures);
    }

    vector<Texture> loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName)
    {
        vector<Texture> textures;

        for ( GLuint i=0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++ )
        {
            aiString str;
            mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);

            GLboolean skip = false;

            //Textur wurde bereits geladen => überspringen 
            for (GLuint j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
            {
                if (textures_loaded[j].path == str)
                {
                    textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
                    skip = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            //Texture wurde noch nicht geladen
            if (!skip)
            {
                Texture texture;
                texture.id = TextureFromFile(str.C_Str(), this->directory);
                texture.type = typeName;
                texture.path = str;
                textures.push_back(texture);

                this->textures_loaded.push_back(texture);
            }
        }
        return textures;
    }
};

GLint TextureFromFile(const char* path, string directory)
{
    string filename = string(path);
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures( 1, &textureID );
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    return textureID;
}
```

This is the code I use to setup the Mesh that make up my Models. Though I'm getting a warning from this file that says that the variable "Texture::id" is not initiliased even though it clearly is.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Shader.h"
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <assimp/types.h>

using namespace std;

struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 Position;
    glm::vec3 Normal;
    glm::vec2 TexCoords;
};

struct Texture
{
    GLuint id;
    string type;
    aiString path;
};

class Mesh
{
public:
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<GLuint> indices;
    vector<Texture> textures;

    Mesh(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<GLuint> indices, vector<Texture> textures)
    {
        this->vertices = vertices;
        this->indices = indices;
        this->textures = textures;

        this->SetupMesh();
    }

    void Draw(Shader shader)
    {
        GLuint diffuseNr = 1;
        GLuint specularNr = 1;

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE + i);

            stringstream ss;
            string number;
            string name = this->textures[i].type;

            if ("texture_diffuse" == name)
            {
                ss << diffuseNr++;
            }
            else if ("texture_specular" == name)
            {
                ss << specularNr++;
            }

            number = ss.str();

            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, (name + number).c_str()), i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textures[i].id);
        }

        //Draw the Mesh
        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < this-> textures.size(); i++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
    }

private:
    GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;

    void SetupMesh()
    {
        glGenVertexArrays( 1, &this->VAO);
        glGenBuffers( 1, &this->VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &this->vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO );
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &this->indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //Vertex Positionen
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)0);

        //Vertex Normals
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof( Vertex, Normal));

        //Vertex Texture coordinates
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof( Vertex,TexCoords ));

        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }
};
```

And this is the class I use to open and later on populate the Window by calling upon it from my main.cpp

```
#include "MeinMesh.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Model.h"

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <iostream>

OpenWindow::OpenWindow(const std::string& title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    :m_Title(title), m_Width(width), m_Height(height), m_Window(nullptr)
{
    /* GLFW initialisieren */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);

    /* Erschaffen des des Windows und Context */
    m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

    if (!m_Window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_Window);

    /* Initialiesieren der GLEW Lib*/
     glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
     GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /*Glew konnte nicht initialisiert werden*/
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        std::cout << "GLEW konnte nicht gestartet werden";
    }

    //Viewport einrichten
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    //Depth enable
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    std::cout << "OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;

}


/* Getting Infos about the Window*/
std::string OpenWindow::GetTitle() const
{
    return m_Title;
}

unsigned int OpenWindow::GetWidth() const
{
    return m_Width;
}

unsigned int OpenWindow::GetHeight()const
{
    return m_Height;
}

// Drawing in the Window
void OpenWindow::Show()
{   //Setup Shader

    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)m_Width / (GLfloat)m_Height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

    Shader myShader("core.vs", "core.frag");

    Model Castle("Burg und Rammbock.obj");
    Model ram("Rammbock.obj");

    bool close = false;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_Window) )
    {
        //Render
        // Colourbuffer leeren
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        myShader.StartShader();

        //Projection Matrix
        glm::mat4 model;
        glm::mat4 view;
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));

        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(myShader.Program, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(myShader.Program, "view");
        GLint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(myShader.Program, "projection");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        // Zeichnen der Modelle
        Castle.Draw(myShader);
        ram.Draw(myShader);

        //Screen Buffer wechseln
        glfwSwapBuffers(m_Window);

    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I added the files for the models to the project and AssImp is comipled correctly.
I tried using diffrent file formats and using UTF8 and UTF16, I have excluded the .obj files from the Build but no matter what I did AssImp is unable to load the files.

Comment: Have you tried giving the full absolute path to `MyFile.obj`?

Comment: Just tried it again, changed the entire thing out of desperation. Users\myname\source\repos\... and still getting the same error.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a path problem: if you pass a relative path, it'll be relative to the current directory, which might be at different locations depending on how you launch the executable. Where is `MyFile.obj`, really?

Answer (score 0):

You did everything perfectly fine, except for specifying your "path" parameter for the importer's ReadFile function.

```
 void loadModel(string path)
{
    //Datei mit Assimp auslesen
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
```

The function you tried to call rather accepts a char *path, which is a C-style null terminated character array.

[Documentation of Assimp importer.ReadFile method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXRjx.png)

Instead of directly supplying the "std::string path" (which is a object) as in your "loadModel(string path)", you must convert it to a char * using [c_str()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

```
 void loadModel(string path)
{
    //Datei mit Assimp auslesen
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path.c_str(), aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
```

"path.c_str()" returns only the char* which you specified as your model location;
whereas string as class object is an abstract, managed data structure, aiding in handling long char-arrays or quickly performing searches and such.
Hope you are way past that issue and your game engine is working!

http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#a174418ab41d5b8bc51a044895cb991e5

Comment: `ReadFile` has an overload that takes a `std::string` (it's right below the one you linked). Plus, the OP's error is clearly a runtime one, so their code compiles. So, no, that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your critique, if I am not wrong though, the second overloaded ReadFile(...) takes a "std::string &" as argument (reference), which OP also didn't provide. 
Second: Why should the code not compile? The compiler can either interpret "random_string" as *char array* or *std::string*. And lastly: I did the learnopengl tutorial too and I think I ran into the same issue.  Either way, since this is a learning resource and OP doesn't need sophisticated string operations but only a relative path specified for his opj-loader, they should just rework this portion.

Comment: What do you mean, didn't provide? `void loadModel(string path)` has a `path` parameter of type `std::string`. The compiler doesn't have to "interpret" anything, that's the overload that's going to be selected. Using char arrays and/or pointers is also incredibly error prone, and strings are recommended in any case where interoperability with a C API isn't required. And anyway, that's not their problem: reworking this part of the code wouldn't fix their issue at all, which means your answer should _at best_ be a comment.